# How to select and change first date value in javascript date range widget?

Tags: jquery, widget, daterangepicker

Trying to access the first date to change the value to 01/01/1950.

Have tried

```
$("#startDate").datepicker("setDate", "01/01/1950");
```

```
$("#picker").datepicker("setDate", "01/01/1950 - 10/02/2019");
```

changes the date but not correctly, changes date to 12/31/1969.

screenshot of dom:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOQRP.png

Comment: Your first example works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ocwn41f3/ The second obviously won't because `01/01/1950 - 10/02/2019` isn't a valid date

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you, it is not working on my end, please try with URL [link](https://www.investing.com/equities/amazon-com-inc-historical-data)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future, to set the value of the date widget when the value is hidden:

```
$("#picker").val("01/01/1950 - 10/02/2019");
$("#widgetFieldDateRange").click();
$("#applyBtn").click();
alert(picker.value);
```